# how to make group of radio buttons in spring form?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

**i am creating a quiz application where i want to group options in a radio button list after fetching options from database. My code is below so that one option from optionList of Question object is selected seprately.**

i want to list group of questions and their options in a single page options with their relative questions .if i select option of one question  i should be able to select another option of another question. how do i seprate radio buttons for each questions???

```
@Controller
public class ApiController {
    

@Autowired      
private QuestionRepository qr;    
    @Autowired
    private OptionRepository or;    
    @Autowired
    private ActivitiesCrudRepository acr;

    @RequestMapping("/questions")
    public String ShowQuestions(@ModelAttribute("questions") Question question) {

        return "questions";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/save")
    public String save(@ModelAttribute("questions") Question question) {

        qr.save(question);
        return "questions";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/pq")
    public String playQuiz(Model m, @ModelAttribute("questions") Question qsn) {

        


Iterable<Question> q = qr.findAll();

        System.out.println(q);
        m.addAttribute("q", q);
        return "play-quiz";

    }






<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
    "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ page isELIgnored="false"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form:form action="play" modelAttribute="questions">
        <c:forEach var="temp" items="${q}">
${temp.qsn_Name}<br>
            <c:forEach var="temp1" items="${temp.options}">
                <form:radiobuttons path="options[0].name" value="${temp1.name}"
                    items="${????????????}" />
                <br>
            </c:forEach>
            <br>
        </c:forEach>
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

When using using the taglib function `form:radiobuttons` you don't need to iterate over the options you want in the radiobutton group.

You can replace

```
<c:forEach var="temp1" items="${temp.options}">
    <form:radiobuttons path="options[0].name" value="${temp1.name}"
        items="${????????????}" />
    <br>
</c:forEach>
```

with

```
<form:radiobuttons path="options[0].name" items="${temp.options}" />
```

Be aware of the difference between `form:radiobutton` which create one single button and `form:radiobuttons` which creates the whole group.

See f.x. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/springmvc/springmvc_radiobuttons.htm or https://mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-radiobutton-and-radiobuttons-example/for more examples.

Comment: @Pookar Aryal: Please feel free to accept my answer if you feel it solved you issues, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers